# Aggregate values if value wasn't seen before in group - SQL / ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Trying to do this in Oracle queries but SQL works too. I'm wondering if there are any easy functions or ways to do this , in theory I know how to do this in python (see my example below)

Basically I'm trying to run a total distinct count , lets say monthly for a unique identifier lets use "customer_id" but only have them added to the total if they were not seen in prior months.

If customer 1 was seen in Jan and then again in March. They would only be in the Jan total and counted as 1.
The grand total would be the total number of unique_customers

....In python you would do a list , check to see if the customer is in the list if they are it would do nothing. If they are not they get appended to the list and then added to the sum, total. This is just overall total of unique values though and it would have to do this on a monthly total but in theory this is what I would want

```
l = []
total = 0
customers [12,123,1234,12345,123455]

for i in customers:
    if i in l:
        pass
    else:
        l.append(i)
        total += 1

return total
```

Now that I'm typing this out and thinking about it more though I would do a subquery of unique customer and their min(date) of sale. Then when

```
select count(distinct customer_id), month
from sales
group by month
```

Doesnt work because each unique customer is counted by month....but if I did

```
select count(customer_id), month
from 
(select customer_id, min(month)
from sales
group by customer_id)
group by month
```

that would work as it's only using the customers first sale month as the total? Is there an easier way to do this or does this make sense

Comment: Note that SQL is a language. It's supported by a bunch of products - including Oracle and MS SQL Server... ("_in Oracle queries but SQL works too_")

Comment: Your table holds customer_id and month and customer_id is not a key, am I right?
And what you want, is a table, that holds costomer_id and month with only the first entry of customer_id?

Comment: Doesn't oracle have their own syntax though of TSQL ?

Comment: TSQL is SQL Server's procedural language and PL/SQL is oracle's procedural language; neither of them is derived from the other and they are not SQL (but they can use context-switch to use SQL within them). The language SQL is something separate and both Oracle and SQL server have their own (slightly different) syntaxes for SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to find the first occurrence of each `customer_id`; you can use an analytic function for that and then filter on the first occurrence:

```sql
SELECT customer_id,
       month
FROM   (
  SELECT customer_id,
         month,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY month ) AS rn
  FROM   sales
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sales ( customer_id, month ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2021-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2021-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2021-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2021-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2021-05-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CUSTOMER_ID | MONTH    
> ----------: | :--------
>           1 | 01-JAN-21
>           2 | 01-JAN-21
>           3 | 01-MAR-21
>           4 | 01-APR-21
> ```

If you want to count, for each month, the users who have not been seen before then just take the previous query and aggregate:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(customer_id) AS number_of_new_customers,
       month
FROM   (
  SELECT customer_id,
         month,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY month ) AS rn
  FROM   sales
)
WHERE  rn = 1
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```

Which, for the same sample data, outputs:

> ```
> NUMBER_OF_NEW_CUSTOMERS | MONTH    
> ----------------------: | :--------
>                       2 | 01-JAN-21
>                       1 | 01-MAR-21
>                       1 | 01-APR-21
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=003a69b7da7cb2db212f99ced4778903)*